# Access VBA - ADO Recordset - No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I've run across this error when attempting to query the database with ADO. From searching around I've found that this probably means there is an issue with the SQL that I am using.

```
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim varGetRows As Variant
    Dim sqlStr As String

    sqlStr = "SELECT qryEmpRewardsDetail.PBRID, qryEmpRewardsDetail.ActualReward, qryEmpRewardsDetail.ProratedActual, qryEmpRewardsDetail.Adjust, qryEmpRewardsDetail.Total, qryEmpRewardsDetail.Prorated FROM qryEmpRewardsDetail WHERE qryEmpRewardsDetail.ReviewYearID=8 AND qryEmpRewardsDetail.EmployeeID=30 AND qryEmpRewardsDetail.TypeID=1;"

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.Open sqlStr, CurrentProject.Connection
    varGetRows = rs.GetRows()
```

I've re-written it in a couple of different ways, checked the spelling a hundred times and copied and pasted it into an access query which ran fine.

For the life of me I can't figure out what could be wrong with it. Any ideas on what it could be or some suggestions on how to narrow down the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming *qryEmpRewardsDetail* is a saved query, could it be the cause of the "missing" parameter?  If you temporarily change your code to use this query, do you still get the missing parameter complaint?  `SELECT * FROM qryEmpRewardsDetail;`

Comment: Yeah that gives me the same error, but it works fine when I create a saved query with it. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: We may be able to resolve the problem if you show us the SQL from *qryEmpRewardsDetail*.

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out. It was a problem with the saved query I was referencing. It was needlessly complicated and simplifying it removed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does this run?

```
SELECT * FROM qryEmpRewardsDetail WHERE qryEmpRewardsDetail.ReviewYearID=8 AND qryEmpRewardsDetail.EmployeeID=30 AND qryEmpRewardsDetail.TypeID=1
```

If it does, then you likely spelt a field wrong, add one by one till happy.

Otherwise, try removing each WHERE condition and test between each.

Define your recordset fully just to be safe:

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
rst.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rst.LockType = adLockReadOnly

rst.Open sqlStr

If rst.BOF and rst.EOF Then
    'no records returned
End If

Do While Not rst.EOF
    'Doing stuff with row
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```